# Compare two sheets and check for different values/data and update master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro to compare two worksheets "Master" and "Child" and check for any new/different entry in "Child" sheet as per column A ("ID").

Data in "Master" worksheet:

```
   A            B           C  
1  ID           Name        Sales  
2  10          Sachin     5000  
3  20        Vikas    4000  
4  30        Nitin    7000
```

Data in "Child" worksheet:

```
   A         B        C  
1  ID        Name     Sales  
2  100       Rakesh   4500  
3  30        Nitin    7000  
4  110       Sanket   5500
```

I am trying to add new entries from "Child" (ID=100 & 110) to "Master" sheet.

I have written this code:

```
Sub Compare_and_Update_Data()

Dim Master, Child As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, mlr As Long, clr As Long

Set Master = Worksheets("Master")
Set Child = Worksheets("Child")

mlr = Master.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Master sheet
clr = Child.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Child sheet

For i = 2 To mlr
    For j = 2 To clr

    'Checks column "A" with unique value(ID) from both sheets and if new record found then update records in "A","B" and "C" column in Master sheet
        If Master.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Child.Cells(j, 1) Then
            Master.Cells(i, 1).Value = Child.Cells(j, 1)
            Master.Cells(i, 2).Value = Child.Cells(j, 2)
            Master.Cells(i, 3).Value = Child.Cells(j, 3)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I am not getting desired output.

Can anyone help me to figure out how should I correct the code to update new/different rows in master sheet or any alternate solution will really help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
Sub Compare_and_Update_Data()

Dim Master, Child As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, mlr As Long, mlri As Long, clr As Long

Set Master = Worksheets("Master")
Set Child = Worksheets("Child")

mlr = Master.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Master sheet
clr = Child.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Child sheet

Dim bIDNotfound As Boolean


For j = 2 To clr
    For i = 2 To mlr
    bIDNotfound = False
    'Checks column "A" with unique value(ID) from both sheets and if new record found then update records in "A","B" and "C" column in Master sheet
        If Master.Cells(i, 1).Value = Child.Cells(j, 1) Then

            bIDNotfound = True

        End If
    Next i

    If bIDNotfound = False Then
        mlri = Master.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row from Master sheet
        Master.Cells(mlri + 1, 1).Value = Child.Cells(j, 1)
        Master.Cells(mlri + 1, 2).Value = Child.Cells(j, 2)
        Master.Cells(mlri + 1, 3).Value = Child.Cells(j, 3)
    End If

Next j

End Sub
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but it prints all the data from "Child" sheet to "Master" sheet(both existing and New IDs ). I think due to for loop its giving bIDNotfound for one cell as True and remaining cells as False and then considering False, it prints all..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it doesnt copy all rows from Child.
The thing is because you already have in the child a row named with 30, Nitin, 7000 that is identical to the one in the Master, when the two different are copied, it seems that it copied all.

To test it, in the master, change the row 30, Nitin, 7000 to 30, Nitin, 5000.
After you run the code, you will still see 30, Nitin, 5000. Meaning that it didnt replace it with the one from Child

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to print only different values/ new values. In this case i dont want id=30 as it was already there in master.